# frame animation run infinitely

Tags: android, xml, animation

i have a xml frame animation and i want it to run just once .. but it keeps running infinitely  .. even if i used `isOneShot()`

that's my code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import de.vrallev.tutorial.dialer.R;

public class testanim extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.animtest);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        iv.setImageBitmap(null);
        iv.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.animation);

        final AnimationDrawable mailAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) iv
                .getBackground();
        mailAnimation.isOneShot();
        mailAnimation.start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you misunderstood the method `isOneShot()`. This method returns whether the animation plays only once or not. If you want to set the Animation to run only once you have to call the method `setOneShot (booleanValue)`.
So in your case write something like this: `mailAnimation.setOneShot(true)`

See the documentation on this topic as well ([click](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html#setOneShot%28boolean%29)).